# Can I use Websphere with Spring 3.1 and Ehcache?

Tags: spring, websphere, ehcache

I need to implement Ehcache in a project that uses Spring version 3.1 and Websphere. I tried to google something about this topic but I could'nt find anything. Have you guys ever used those three tools together? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [EhCache docs](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/transactions.html),It will **NOT** detect Websphere Transaction Manager automatically,.

> Automatically Detected Transaction Managers
>
> Ehcache automatically detects and uses the following transaction
>   managers in the following order:

- GenericJNDI (e.g. Glassfish, JBoss, JTOM and any others that register
  themselves in JNDI at the standard location of
  java:/TransactionManager
- Weblogic (since 2.4.0)
- Bitronix
- Atomikos

No configuration is required; they work out of the box. The first found
   is used.

And you can configure it as below.

> If your Transaction Manager is not in the above list or you wish to
>   change the priority, provide your own lookup class based on an
>   implementation of **net.sf.ehcache.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerLookup** and
>   specify it in place of the **Default**TransactionManagerLookup in
>   **ehcache.xml**:

```
<transactionManagerLookup
  class= "com.mycompany.transaction.manager.MyTransactionManagerLookupClass"
  properties="" propertySeparator=":"/>
```

And to integrate & Use Spring with EhCache, refer this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/)

From [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations)s,

> 36.3 Declarative annotation-based caching For caching declaration, the abstraction provides a set of Java annotations:
>
> **@Cacheable** triggers cache population  @CacheEvict triggers cache eviction
>
> **@CachePut** updates the cache without interfering with the method execution
>
> **@Caching** regroups multiple cache operations to be applied on a
>   method
>
> **@CacheConfig** shares some common cache-related settings at class-level